# Passing parameter to javascript function form HTML but using ejs

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have the current code in my 'index.ejs' file. I would like to pass the item as a parameter to the `deleteItem()` and `updateItem()` functions. However, simply writing item is not working.

```
<% items.forEach((item) => { %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span class="description"><%= item %></span>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" id="delete-button" onclick="deleteItem()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
         </button>
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" id="update-button" onclick="updateItem()">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
          </button>
     </li>
<% }) %>
```

To be specific, I want the individual items in the `forEach` loop to be passed when their buttons are clicked. I am using embedded javascript as you can see.

I have looked up answers saying one needs to make use of `document.getElementById()`, but I tried implementing it and it didn't work. Not sure if I did it correctly, though.

Comment: You can't do that; ejs templates are processed on the server, and the <%...%> code you use server-side is used to generate the document that is sent to the browser. That onclick code runs inside the browser, and the browser has no idea what `item` is because it doesn't exist in the browser context. One way to approach this (based on the assumption that your website is primarily backend based): instead of a button with an onclick property, use something like `<a href="/items?action=delete&id=<%= i %>" ...>`. For that you need the index: `items.forEach((item, i)`

Comment: If you do have a frontend, use `onclick="deleteItem(<%= i %>)"` instead, but I'm kind of wary of suggesting that unless you show what `deleteItem` looks like.

Comment: `deleteItem()` and `updateItem()` are function that call PUT and DELETE requests using fetch

Comment: Ok, do that then. `i` is the zero based index  of the `items` array, so the server should handle that correctly.